CreateSalesforceObject creating duplicate records
I have been sending email campaigns using which my subscribers can click on a cta button and request a callback. This CTA redirects to a cloud page which consists of the AMPscript to create a callback record for my custom object 'Demographics'. I send these campaigns multiple times to the same users. Of late, the script creates 2-5 duplicate records. The row count logic didn't work because there are similar records generated previously as well. How can I ensure only a single record is generated.
%%[
set @id = _subscriberkey
set @communities = 'community_id'
 var @createdemographic
set @createddemographic =
CreateSalesforceObject('Demographics__c', 5, 'Contact__c', @id, 'Community__c', @communities, 'Answer__c', 'Yes', 'Name', 'Requested a callback?', 'MCSource__c', 'Campaign1')
]%%


I'd suggest excluding test sends and adding some debugging output:
%%[

set @debug = 1
set @id = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @isTestSend = AttributeValue("_IsTestSend")
set @Demographic__c_Id = ''

if not empty(@id) and @isTestSend == "false" then

  set @communities = 'community_id'

  set @Demographic__c_Id = CreateSalesforceObject('Demographics__c', 5, 
      'Contact__c', @id
    , 'Community__c', @communities
    , 'Answer__c', 'Yes'
    , 'Name', 'Requested a callback?'
    , 'MCSource__c', 'Campaign1'
  )

endif

if @debug == 1 then

  output(concat("<br>id: ", @id))
  output(concat("<br>isTestSend: ", @isTestSend))
  output(concat("<br>communities: ", @communities))
  output(concat("<br>Demographic__c_Id: ", @Demographic__c_Id))

endif

]%%

Just toggle the debug flag to 0 when you've completed your testing.
